# ValueError with for loop with 2 elements over 2 cols _ pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iteration, calculation

I am trying to calculate the mean+3*std for every row in 2 cols of my df (named: controls), and then add value as a new col.
My code is this:

```
for l, r  in controls[['means1', 'std1']]:
    controls['Threshold']=l+(3*r)
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I would appreciate any advice or help!

Thank you,
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a for-loop if possible in Pandas. It's slow because it has to work through the slower interpreted Python code rather than nice and fast C via Numpy. You can do this just by:

```
controls['threshold'] = controls['means1'] + 3 * controls['std1']
```

Or [alternatively](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html),

```
controls.eval('threshold = means1 + 3 * std1', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Dear ifly6, Thank you for your reply, and the explanation provided. The first solution worked! So, did not need to use the .eval( ) one, but I was happy to learn about it. I appreciate your time - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the loop. For a calculation like this, you can just multiply and add the entire column at once.

```
controls['Threshold'] = controls['means1'] + (3 * controls['std1'])
```

This will be simpler and faster than row-by-row iteration, because Pandas can do the entire operation in numpy. But if you're set on iterating over rows, take a look at [iterrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas).

Comment: Dear Nick ODell, Thank you for taking the time to reply. Your solution works fine. I understand now I should do it this way in the future, with col calculations. Thanks.